# JFileChooser save dialog with multiple file extensions

Tags: java, jfilechooser, file-extension, writer

I am trying to save a file using `JFileChooser` and a `TxtWriter` class for the `.txt` option and a `XmlWriter` class for the `.xml` option. At first i tried only to create the `txt` option, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code for the **`JFileChooser`**:

```
JMenuItem mntmCreate = new JMenuItem("Create Report");
mntmCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        switch (chooser.showSaveDialog(frame)){
        case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
            File fileToWrite = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            TxtWriter txtwriter = new TxtWriter(taxpayer);
            txtwriter.writeReport(taxpayer);
            System.out.println("Report taxpayer: " +taxpayer.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

The class **`TxtWriter`**:

```
public class TxtWriter implements Writer {

    public TxtWriter(Taxpayer taxpayer) {
        writeReport(taxpayer);
    }

    public void writeReport(Taxpayer taxpayer) {

        PrintWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("Report.txt", "UTF-8");
            printToWriterTaxpayerInfo(taxpayer, writer);
            printToWriterTaxDetails(taxpayer, writer);
            printToWriterReceiptsAmountDetails(taxpayer, writer);
            writer.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printToWriterTaxpayerInfo(Taxpayer taxpayer, PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.println("Name: " + taxpayer.getName());
        writer.println("AFM: " + taxpayer.getTaxRegistrationNumber());
        writer.println("Status: " + taxpayer.getStatus());
        writer.println("Income: " + taxpayer.getIncome());
    }

    public void printToWriterTaxDetails(Taxpayer taxpayer, PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.println("Basic Tax: " + taxpayer.getBasicTax());
        writer.println("Tax Increase: " + taxpayer.getTaxIncrease());
        writer.println("Total Tax: "
                + (taxpayer.getBasicTax() + taxpayer.getTaxIncrease()));
    }

    public void printToWriterReceiptsAmountDetails(Taxpayer taxpayer,
            PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.println("Total Receipts Gathered: "
                + taxpayer.computeTotalReceiptsGathered());
        writer.println("Entertainment: "
                + taxpayer.computeReceiptsAmountForKindEntertainment());
        writer.println("Basic: " + taxpayer.computeReceiptsAmountForKindBasic());
        writer.println("Travel: "
                + taxpayer.computeReceiptsAmountForKindTravel());
        writer.println("Health: "
                + taxpayer.computeReceiptsAmountForKindHealth());
        writer.println("Other: " + taxpayer.computeReceiptsAmountForKindOther());
    }
}
```

Similarly, there is an `XmlWriter` class for the `xml` file.
I want to use the these two writer classes for the creation of the different file types.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a filter in JFileChooser to allow only text and xml files.

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
jf.setFileFilter(filter);
```

or use addChoosableFileFilter

```
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("XMl and text Files", "xml","txt");
```

Comment: but then i still can't figure out how to use the `XmlWriter` and `TxtWriter` class i made

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079709/file-saved-with-jfilechooser-showsavedialog-even-on-cancel